# Tips for running Craft in Microsoft IIS

Tags: config, hosting

My client prefers to use a Microsoft IIS hosting environment he already has. After some gnashing of teeth I have managed to get it working there, but it is painfully slow (unlike my local LAMP version).

I was inclined to assume some sort of shared server MySQL bottleneck but the host's response to this thought has been…

> I don't see any bottlenecks on the server itself, mysql connections to the server and queries on it are running very quickly so I would be looking at the code itself. I've done some tests with simple php + mysql connections on the server and these run very fast, so this is pointing at the CMS doing something slowly, but I'm not familiar with the CMS to know what this is.

Does anyone have experience of Craft running **well** in IIS on a shared server?

Is there any particular config that is worth trying to get it to do so?

Comment: Meanwhile… the host has offered a test Linux environment to work with. It will be interesting to see if there are obvious differences in performance.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you running? PHP 7 is notably faster.

Answer (score 2):

I run Craft on IIS/Win 10 on my main development box and don't have issues with it.  Don't recall having to jump through hoops to get it working, either.

I suspect it's more of the "shared server" that's the issue, but you can start by enabling [devMode](https://craftcms.com/support/dev-mode) in Craft and check the timestamped profiling output (code and database) in the browser's console and `craft/storage/runtime/logs` to try and narrow down where the time is going.

Comment: Belated thanks, Brad. I suspect you are right. The client in question is now running it under LAMP and performance is much better, though still sluggish. Pretty sure it's his host that he is wedded to.